# Gerrit error log:"Unable to authenticate user by Authorization request header". what's going on?

Tags: gerrit

I had install gerrit-v2.11 on ubuntu server v-12.04, using apache2 do Reverse Proxy. Here is my gerrit.config:

```
[gerrit]
basePath = git
canonicalWebUrl = http://192.168.26.47:8081
[database]
type = h2
database = db/ReviewDB
[index]
type = LUCENE
[auth]
type = HTTP
[sendemail]  
smtpServer = smtp.exmail.qq.com
smtpServerPort = 465  
smtpEncryption = ssl  
smtpUser = gerrit@pisen.com.cn  
smtpPass = PS1024mail
sslVerify = false  
from=CodeReview<gerrit@pisen.com.cn> 
[container]
user = mng
javaHome = /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_65/jre
[sshd]
listenAddress = *:29418
[httpd]
listenUrl = proxy-http://192.168.26.47:8081/
[cache]
directory = cache
[download]
command = checkout
command = cherry_pick
command = pull
command = format_patch
scheme = http
scheme = anon_http
scheme = anon_git
scheme = repo_download
scheme = ssh
```

and the apache2 default file:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName 192.168.26.47

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyVia Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    <Location /login/>
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "Gerrit Code Review"
            AuthBasicProvider file
            AuthUserFile /adm-servers/gerrit/review_site/etc/passwords
            Require valid-user
    </Location>

AllowEncodedSlashes On
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.26.47:8081/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8081/
```

Now it works. But, it takes very long time to login(about 1-2 min):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1ueJ.png)

I checked the log file, there is one error:

```
[2016-03-18 09:51:24,268] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector : Started ServerConnector@5ced0537{HTTP/1.1}{192.168.26.47:8081}
[2016-03-18 09:51:24,268] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server : Started @13804ms
[2016-03-18 09:51:24,269] INFO  com.google.gerrit.pgm.Daemon : Gerrit Code Review 2.11 ready
[2016-03-18 10:05:03,957] ERROR com.google.gerrit.httpd.auth.container.HttpLoginServlet : Unable to authenticate user by Authorization request header.  Check container or server configuration.
```

I searched for this error information, and was told that the most probable reason was Gerrit and apache using the same port. Obviously, in my config file, this ports were not same as each other.

I also captured the packages:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLntI.png)

The capture talk of that, the TCP connection colsed while login. And i doubt the error "Unable to authenticate user by Authorization request header" cause the connection to be colsed.

Any body know what's going on about "Unable to authenticate user by Authorization request header"?

Comment: If they both start, then the don't listen to the same port. But there is sth. odd in your config: the ports in Gerrit's `canonicalWebUrl` and Apache's `<VirtualHost *:xxxx>` should match.  Use 8080 here. But that still should not be your real issue.

Comment: TKS for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am Ok now,but not found the cause.
I will try a new environment to find it when I have the time.
Here is my config detail(init gerrit-2.12.war to '/usr/local/gerrit' ):

## vim /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost [My_IP]:80>
    ServerName [My_IP]

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyVia Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Proxy *:80>
          Order deny,allow
          Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    <Location '/login/'>
      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "YuhuiXU Gerrit Code Review"
      Require valid-user
      AuthBasicProvider file
      AuthUserFile  /usr/local/gerrit/etc/passwds
    </Location>
    AllowEncodedSlashes On
    ProxyPass / http://[My_IP]:8081/
</VirtualHost>
```

## vim /usr/local/gerrit/etc/gerrit.config

```
[gerrit]
    basePath = git
    canonicalWebUrl = http://test026:80/
[database]
    type = mysql
    hostname = localhost
    database = reviewdb
    username = gerrit
[index]
    type = LUCENE
[auth]
    type = HTTP
[receive]
    enableSignedPush = false
[sendemail]
    smtpServer = localhost
[container]
    user = root
    javaHome = /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
[sshd]
    listenAddress = *:29418
[httpd]
    listenUrl = http://[My_IP]:8081/
[cache]
    directory = cache
```

Hope this will help you.